# Create table with Javascript array and object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have one array and one object:

```
labels = ['ID','Name']; 
object = {
    ["id": "1", 'name': "richard"],
    ["id": "2", 'name': "santos"]
};
```

and I have to create a table like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Richard</td>
        <td>Santos</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is that: 

The "object" variable sometimes could have different key names so I have to create this table dynamically with other objects, I'm trying to do this all day but no success, can anyone help me? I'm new to Javascript.
obs: the label and the object vars always have the same size.

Some kind of objects.

```
var labels = ['ID','NOME'];
var object = {
    ["id": "1", 'nome': "richard"],
    ["id": "2", 'nome': "adriana"]
};

var labels = ['ID','NAME', 'PLATE'];
var object = {
    ["id": "1", 'nome': "jetta",  'plate': "DFG-1222"],
    ["id": "2", 'nome': "fusion", 'plate': "DFF-3342"]
};
```

Comment: It would help to see some other variations of the object and corresponding table.

Comment: What did you try so far and how did it not work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8mkbbx/

Comment: The data structures ain't gonna work; (a) as written, `object` will throw a syntax error. (b) objects are orderless

Comment: Could you fix a question by changing parenthis and square brackets order like: var labels = ['id','name'], object = [{"id":"1",'name': "richard"},{"id":"2",'name': "santos"}];

Comment: (OT) Richard, I just edited your question - for future questions please use the correct apostrophe character, ' and not \` - the latter encloses code segments. Example, enclosed in backticks \`: `this is code`. You have three different single-quote characters on your keyboard - but they are all very different: one is for composing accents, one is for apostrophes and single quotes, one is backticks - and that last one has that special formatting meaning here.

Comment: I also made minor changes to fix a problem with { and [ in objects.

Comment: @agershun Please do NOT fix code errors in people's questions. That is an ANSWER. The error is the reason people asked in the first place - what's the point of editing the question instead of giving an answer? Show correct code in the answer, leave the errors in the question. IMHO. If you edit away errors people will wonder why there ever was a problem.

Comment: @Richard Feliciano - If the answer is helpful, you can accept it by checking the tick mark on the left side of the answer.If the answer is helpful in anyway and if you respect the time :), you can up vote the answer by clicking the triangle facing up side, beside the question.

Comment: @Mörre It is reasonable. Accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Two issues at first:

1. Is that N**a**me or N**o**me? Please fix your typo (I know Nome is French, so if it's not typo, I suggest you introduce an [**i18n**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) solution).
2. Also please mind your syntax errors (some have given suggested edits that you could consider).

After that, here's my approach for programmatically create tables based on input data:

```js
function buildTable(labels, objects, container) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

  var theadTr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var theadTh = document.createElement('th');
    theadTh.innerHTML = labels[i];
    theadTr.appendChild(theadTh);
  }
  thead.appendChild(theadTr);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  for (j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
    var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (k = 0; k < labels.length; k++) {
      var tbodyTd = document.createElement('td');
      tbodyTd.innerHTML = objects[j][labels[k].toLowerCase()];
      tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTd);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tbodyTr);
  }
  table.appendChild(tbody);

  container.appendChild(table);
}

var labels1 = ['ID', 'Name']; 
var objects1 = [
  {"id": "1", 'name': "richard"},
  {"id": "2", 'name': "santos"}
];

var labels2 = ['ID', 'NOME'];
var objects2 = [
  {"id": "1", 'nome': "richard"},
  {"id": "2", 'nome': "adriana"}
];

var labels3 = ['ID', 'NAME', 'PLATE'];
var objects3 = [
  {"id": "1", 'name': "jetta",  'plate': "DFG-1222"},
  {"id": "2", 'name': "fusion", 'plate': "DFF-3342"}
];

buildTable(labels1, objects1, document.getElementById('a'));
buildTable(labels2, objects2, document.getElementById('b'));
buildTable(labels3, objects3, document.getElementById('c'));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"><p>Table 1</p></div>
<div id="b"><p>Table 2</p></div>
<div id="c"><p>Table 3</p></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a working procedure from our project.  It has three parameters:

```
htmlTable(selector, data_array [, column_names]);
```

***column_names*** parameter is optional: if you omit it the function creates column names from first row (if it exists).

It creates HTML tags directly into the DOM, but it can be rewritten to generate HTML as a string if you need . See the working snippet below:

```js
var labels = ['id','name']; 
var object = [{"id":"1",'name': "richard"},{"id":"2",'name': "santos"}];
htmlTable("#res0",object, labels);

var labels = ['id','nome']; 
var object = [{"id":"1",'nome': "richard"},{"id":"2",'nome': "adriana"}];
htmlTable("#res1",object, labels);

var labels = ['id','name', 'plate']; 
var object = [{"id":"1",'name': "jetta",'plate': "DFG-1222"},
              {"id":"2",'name': "fusion",'plate': "DFF-3342"}];
htmlTable("#res2",object, labels);

// Without labels array
var data3 = [{a:1,c:2},{a:3,c:3}];
htmlTable("#res3",data3);

function htmlTable(selector, data, columns) {
 var sel = document.querySelector(selector);
 if(!sel) {
  throw new Error('Selected HTML element is not found');
 }; 

 if((!columns) || columns.length == 0) {
        columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
 }

 var tbe = document.createElement('table');
 var thead = document.createElement('thead');
 tbe.appendChild(thead);

  var tre = document.createElement('tr');
  for(var i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
    var the = document.createElement('th');
    the.textContent = columns[i];
    tre.appendChild(the);
  }
  thead.appendChild(tre);

 var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
 tbe.appendChild(tbody);
 for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
  var tre = document.createElement('tr');
  for(var i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
   var the = document.createElement('td');
   the.textContent = data[j][columns[i]];
   tre.appendChild(the);
  }
  tbody.appendChild(tre);
 };
 emptyDOMChildren(sel);
 sel.appendChild(tbe);
};

// Utility function to fast delete all children of element if it is not empty
// Can be replaced with simple but relatively "slower" container.innerHTML = "";
function emptyDOMChildren (container){
  var len = container.childNodes.length;
  while (len--) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="res0"></div>
<div id="res1"></div>
<div id="res2"></div>
<div id="res3"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script   src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
arr1 = [
{"Name":"Peter","RollNo" : 1234,},
{"Name":"John","RollNo" : 1234,},
{"Name":"Kevin","RollNo" : 1234,},
];

$.each(arr1, function(i){
   var templateString = '<table class="table card"><thead> <tr><td><p>My name is: '+arr1[i].Name+'</p><p>My RollNo is: '+arr1[i].RollNo+'</p></td></tr></thead></table>';
$('#test').append(templateString);
})
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improvement to @Kaushar*s answer with a html table with header. It is a quick and working solution with pure array, no objects.

```js
ags = [
  ['proj', 'Duales Studium zum Master of Science Wirtschaftsinformatik'],
  ['Kess', 'Systemadministrator Linux'],
  ['foo', 'Customer Success Engineer (EMEA)'],
]

templateString = '<table class=table><tr><th>Firma</th><th>Job</th><th>Status</th><th>Datum</th></tr>'
$.each(ags, function (i) {
  templateString += '<tr><td>' + ags[i][0] + '</td><td>' + ags[i][1] + '</td><td>Status</td><td>Datum</td></tr>'
})
templateString += '</table>'
$('#fa').append(templateString)
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
      <div id="fa"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several similar questions any many answers in SO which are mostly tailored to a specific case. However with a little effort you can easily come up with your own templating abstraction by using native JS [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Perhaps you can even give up using templating engine libraries for such jobs in the future.

The following code is pure JS. Lets start with a proper data.

```
var data = { labels: ['ID','Name']
           , rows  : [ {"id": "1", 'name': "richard"}
                     , {"id": "2", 'name': "santos"}
                     ]
           };
```

Now let's define a `tableTemplate` function which takes the `data` and gives us an html table.

```
function tableTemplate(data){
  return `
    <table>
      <tr> ${data.labels.map(label => html`
             <th>$${label}</th>`).join("")}
      </tr>${data.rows.map(row => html`
      <tr>
             <td>$${row.id}</td>
             <td>$${row.name}</td>
      </tr>`).join("")}
    </table>`;
}
```

So what is this `` html` `` thingy and also that `$$`?

- First of all `` html` `` is just a generic [tag function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) that we define only once and without modifying it, we can use it for all of our templeting functions.
- `$$` on the other hand is simple. The first `$` is just a simple string character and the second one is the escaping `$` character for variables in templete strings such as `${x}`. We can use a tag function to validate our html code by escaping invalid html characters like `&`, `>`, `<`, `"`, `'` or `` ` ``. The version i give below looks a little convoluted but it's really simple and very useful. It basically escapes invalid html characters and provides a "raw" version of the template string.

Please follow above links for further information. Here it is;

```
function html(lits,...vars){
  var esc = { "&": "&amp;"
            , ">": "&gt;"
            , "<": "&lt;"
            , '"': "&quot;"
            , "'": "&#39;"
            , "`": "&#96;"
            };
  return lits.raw
             .reduce( (res,lit,i) => (res += lit.endsWith("$") ? lit.slice(0,-1) + [...vars[i].toString()].reduce((s,c) => s += esc[c] || c, "")
                                                               : lit + (vars[i] || ""))
                    , ""
                    );
                                                 
}
```

Now, it's time to put everything together for a working sample. Lets also add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags and some CSS this time.

```js
function html(lits,...vars){
  var esc = { "&": "&amp;"
            , ">": "&gt;"
            , "<": "&lt;"
            , '"': "&quot;"
            , "'": "&#39;"
            , "`": "&#96;"
            };
  return lits.raw
             .reduce( (res,lit,i) => (res += lit.endsWith("$") ? lit.slice(0,-1) + [...vars[i].toString()].reduce((s,c) => s += esc[c] || c, "")
                                                               : lit + (vars[i] || ""))
                    , ""
                    );
                                                 
}

function tableTemplate(data){
  return `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>${data.labels.map(label => html`
               <th>$${label}</th>`).join("")}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>${data.rows.map(row => html`
        <tr>
               <td>$${row.id}</td>
               <td>$${row.name}</td>
        </tr>`).join("")}
      </tbody>
    </table>`;
}

var data = { labels: ['ID','Name']
           , rows  : [ {"id": 1, 'name': "richard"}
                     , {"id": 2, 'name': "santos"}
                     , {"id": 3, 'name': "<ömer & 'x'>"}
                     ]
           };
document.write(tableTemplate(data));
```

```css
table {
  background-color: LightPink;
  border          : 0.2em solid #00493E;
  border-radius   : 0.4em;
  padding         : 0.2em
  }
thead {
  background-color: #00493E;
  color           : #E6FFB6
  }
tbody {
  background-color: #E6FFB6;
  color           : #00493E
  }
```

Obviously you can now insert `<syle>` tag or `class="whatever"` attribute into your quasi HTML template literal in the `tableTemplate` function just the way you would normally do in an HTML text file.

Also please note that if you `console.log` the resulting html text string, thanks to the raw convertion, it would beautifully display (according to your indenting in the `tableTemplate` function) just like below...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>richard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>santos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td>317</td>
           <td>&lt;ömer &amp; &#39;x&#39;&gt;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```